# Explicit KE metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, kahler-einstein-metric, ricci-curvature

Does there exist an explicit example of a

- Ricci-flat, non-flat metric on a closed manifold?
- Kaehler--Einstein, non-flat metric on a closed manifold (excluding metrics on homogeneous spaces and metrics on surfaces)?

Comment: If Ricci is 0 or -1 then the isometry group is discrete (up to flat factors) I understand there are no explicit examples. If Ricci is 1 there might be some toric, like the blow-up of projective plane at three points. I don't know what is the status for co-homogeneity one

Comment: This depends on what one means by 'explicit'. For example, we know lots of 'explicit' compact Riemannian surfaces with $K\equiv-1$ in the form $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper half plane endowed with its complete conformal metric of curvature $K\equiv-1$ and $\Gamma\subset \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is a discrete subgroup.  These are not homogeneous (though they are locally homogeneous), and one can't get more explicit than that. Now take products of such $2$-dimensional  examples, to get explicit Kähler-Einstein metrics on compact complex manifolds of any desired dimension.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat:  Yes, there are compact complex ball quotients in any dimension, and these are not products and not globally homogeneous.  Riemann surfaces are simply the lowest dimensional examples.